# How to use bitcoin on Debian?

Tags: linux

I want to use bitcoin in Debian. I want to be able to receive BTC and make payments in BTC.

I want to keep my wallet locally, on my computer. I want a light client, I don't want to download the entire blockchain. I simply want to be able to pay and receive BTC.

What should I use?

When I search for this, I'm surprised to not find any binary packages for Debian. Last time I used BTC was many years ago, and it seems there still isn't any binary packages, for something as commonplace as Debian? Do I really need to download and compile the code myself?

Frustrated, I tried to compile bitcoin-qt, installed a ton of dependencies, but I encounter the following:

```
configure: error: libdb_cxx headers missing, Bitcoin Core requires this library for wallet functionality (--disable-wallet to disable wallet functionality)
```

Tried searching for this, hoping it was just another dependency, but I can't find a simple fix.

I also look at this question: https://superuser.com/questions/699315/how-to-install-bitcoin-qt-wallet-on-debian-7

But it seems to be too old, the instructions (downloading the key) no longer works.

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/install_db4.sh ?

Comment: Have had good luck with a similar script.  On Debian I've always had to build libdb from source, and sometimes link the headers explicitly when building bitcoin.